# Query regarding dijkstra algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra

I am trying to find shortest path between two nodes in a dataset. I
implemented dijkstra algorithm and am using it to prove
given two nodes (like: Andrew_Card
and Dick_Cheney) there does not
exist a path between the source and destination. However, I am finding
that my program is getting killed by the operating system.

After debugging I found that the problem could be related to resource
allocation in RAM. As for dijkstra algorithm, if the number of nodes,
n=16,375,503, then the space requirement is

```
 n*n = 16,375,503 * 16,375,503 > 10^{14}.
```

To run this algorithm in memory we need at least

```
(10^{14} * 4) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) = 10^5 GB  (approximately equal)
of RAM.
```

So, it is not possible to find the shortest path using
dijkstra if we intend to keep a large connected graph in-memory.
Please correct me if I am wrong as I am stuck on this since a long time? Or if there could be some other possible reason which I should check, then please point me to it too.

I implemented the program in C++

No. of edges=25,908,132

Comment: How many edges does the graph have?

Comment: No. of edges=25,908,132

Comment: yeah that's a very large number...But what error are you getting. BTW you have to use debugger in this case to get to know what exactly is happening...

Comment: Do you really need Dijkstra to prove nonexistence? Wouldn't simple BFS suffice?

Comment: Are you stuck with Dijkstra Algorithm? Is there a chance to choose another approach? Also, is there a change to optimize number of nodes?

Comment: Dijksta has a high consumption of memory and if your'e convinced this is causing your problem, consider changing the search algorithm. For instance try out the Iterative Deepening Algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search.

It's both complete and optimal

Comment: I would second @user2040251's answer. Since you only have 2M edges and 1M nodes, you can use an adjacency list of about 1 million entries each 2 records long on average. This means that the memory requirement is most likely below 1G, not 10^5 G. If you use a 64-bit c++ compiler and the right data structure, memory shouldn't be an issue at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the number of edges is relatively low(so that all edges can fit into main memory), you can just store the graph using adjacency list. It requires `O(V + E)` memory, instead of `O(V^2)`. Moreover, you can use Dijkstra's algorithm with a priority queue. It works well for sparse graphs(it has `O(E log V)` time complexity). This approach should work fine for a graph with about `2 * 10^7` vertices and edges(a good implementation can easily fit into main memory and run for no more than several minutes).

Answer (score 3):

If you need JUST the distance between two nodes, use something like `A*`.

But if you're doing all points shortest paths, then you're definitely stuck with `O(n^2)` space. You're finding `O(n^2)` answers - so you can't really do any better than having to store all of them.

Comment: A* and Dijkstra are similar with the exception that Dijkstra uses no heuristic. A* is a specialized case of Dijkstra, and if he uses Dijkstra, chances are no admissable heuristic is available.

Comment: He said `O(n^2)` tho - I was under the impression that meant he was doing all-pairs. Dijkstra for just single-source is `O(n)` too.

Comment: @AndersNK, Dijkstra is a special case of A*, not the other way around.

Comment: Using A* requires there be an admissable heuristic - if you don't have an admissable heuristic you can't use A*, but must use Dijkstra or another search method. @Avakar, yeah I know i switched the two - apologies (can't edit it)!

Answer (score 2):

In terms of making sure that your program is indeed running out of memory, wrap your callsite in a try-catch block and see if you are getting a std::bad_alloc exception. Until you see the exception you are catching, don't make assumptions about which part of your program is failing

In terms of finding the shortest route between two nodes, you probably should up more literature to find what is the most suitable algorithm for your use case.

A*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Contraction hierarchy: http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/schultes/hwy/contract.pdf

Comment: If it is on Liniux, it will probably just get terminated by the OOM killer without an exception ever being thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You should find a way to reduce number of nodes. Your number of nodes are high. You could use Voronoi Diagram to reduce number of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In improvement could be to store vertexes in the priority queue just once. And update the priority queue, instead of adding the same vertex to the priority queue again and again.